# How to create a symmetry correlation matrix easier in R?

Tags: r

I have a correlation matrix similar to:

[image]

It's just an example, my actual matrix is much larger than this. I only want to type the upper-triangle or lower-triangle of the matrix. The problem is that I only know how to type the entire matrix......

In the example, is there any way to give just (1, 0.31, 1, 0.32 ... etc) for the lower-traiangle to create a whole correlation matrix?

Comment: Try `m1 <- cor(mtcars); m1[upper.tri(m1)] <- NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `v` is a vector giving the lower triangular part of the correlation matrix including the diagonal by column then:

```
# test data
nms <- c("a", "b", "c")
v <- c(1, .2, .1, 1, .1, 1) 

n <- length(nms)
m <- diag(n)
dimnames(m) <- list(nms, nms)
m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <- v
m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(m)]
```

giving:

```
> m
    a   b   c
a 1.0 0.2 0.1
b 0.2 1.0 0.1
c 0.1 0.1 1.0
```

**Note:** Since R stores matrices by column providing the input by column would be more usual than by row but if `v` contains the lower triangle by row then swap `lower.tri` and `upper.tri` in the above.